# new category list.phtml calling whole catalog

Tags: category-products, list.phtml

I am trying to create a new list.phtml for a category that has a bunch of smaller products for our store. I got everything working right, except for the fact that the list.phtml is calling my whole catalog and not the actual category that was clicked on. Anyone know how I can change this, with out setting a category id to the specific list.phtml, so I can continue to use it for other categories as well?

```
<?php
                // some helpers
                $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                $catalog = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setStoreId($storeId);
                $productCount = $this->getData('num_products');

$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')    
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)    
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)             
                        ->setPageSize($productCount);
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);


/* To display product by category id */
  if($categoryId=$this->getData('category_id')){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
      } ?>

  <div class="inner-div">
        <?php     // if no products are in list, display some text
                 if (!$collection->count()) :
        ?>
        <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products at the moment.') ?></p>
        <?php else : ?>

     <?php if($categoryId=$this->getData('category_id')) { 
              $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
      ?>
        <h2 class="category-pro-title"><span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span></h2>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h2 class="category-pro-title"><span><?php echo $this->__('Category List') ?></span></h2>
    <?php } ?>


<div class="category-products">
  <div class="products small-list">     
        <?php
                $_collectionSize = $collection->count();
                $_columnCount = 4;
                $i = 0;                
                foreach ($collection as $_product) :
                        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_product->getId());

        ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>            
        <?php endif ?>
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-area">
     <div class="product-image-area">

       <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><img alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image') ?>"></a>  
     </div> <!--product-image-area-->
     <div class="details-area">
       <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                  <?php $prod_name = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ; 
                  if(strlen($prod_name) > 17) {echo substr($prod_name,0,17)."...";}else {echo $prod_name;}?>
             </a>
        </h2>
        <?php
                        $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
                                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                                ->load($_product->getId());
                        if($summaryData->getRatingSummary()){ ?>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                        <div class="rating" style="width: <?php echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary().'%'; ?>"></div>
                                </div> <!--rating-box-->
                            </div> <!--ratings-->
        <?php } else { ?>  
                            <div class="ratings"><div class="rating-box"><div style="width:0%" class="rating"></div></div></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
     </div> <!--details-area-->                     
   </div> <!--item-area-->
</div> <!--item-->      
            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>            
            <?php endif ?>

                <?php endforeach ?>
      </div> <!--products small-list-->    
    </div> <!--category-products-->

        <?php endif ?>  <!--Endif !$collection->count() -->
  </div> <!--inner-div-->
```

Answer (score 1):

This oughtta do what you need:

```
<?php

$categoryid = 12;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this replacing my //some helpers?

Comment: @user3760917 yes

Answer (score 0):

Just change `if($categoryId=$this->getData('category_id'))` with:

```
$currCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($currCategory && $categoryId=$currCategory->getId())
```

Unless you are using a widget you need `Mage::registry('current_category')` to get the current category.